# In nested IIf statements, extract number from end of string, add to that number, then concatenate back to string

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a field that will populate the time point of a form. For instance, there are forms with time points of 100 days, 180 days, 1 year, 2 year, 3 year...20 year, 22 year, 24 year. I have a field that is structured for short text and stores these time points as 100, 180, A1, A2, A3...A20, A22, A24. I'm trying to build an append query that take the current time point as input, and will append a new row with the next time point populated. So, given a row for time point of A15, I'd want the appended row to have a time point of A16. Row A20 input, append a row with A22. I can handle 100-->180, 180-->A1, but A1-->A2 and A20-->A22 are trickier for me. I have an IIf statement that I'm trying to make as simple as possible, so as not to get the "the expression you entered is too complex" error in MS Access Query Design. Right now I have:

```
IIf([Field4]="100","180",
IIf([Field4]="180","A1",
IIf([Field4] Like "A?", `NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE`,
IIf([Field4] Like "A1?", `NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE`,
IIf([Field4] Like "A2?", `NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE`)))))
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to handle the result for the nested IIfs. These are string fields, so I can't just do +1 and +2. Can I separate the number from the text ("A") , add +1 or +2 to that number, and then concatenate that back to the "A"?

OR would all of this be better in VBA? How do you get started on an append query in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the only prefix letter used is "A", consider:

`IIf(Left(Field4, 1) = "A", "A" & Mid(Field4, 2) + 1, IIf(Field4 = "100", "180", IIf(Field4 = "180", "A1", Field4)))`

Or:

`Switch(Left(Field4, 1) = "A","A" & Mid(Field4,2) + 1, Field4 = "100","180", Field4 = "180","A1", True,Field4)`

Comment: Mid() seems to have done the trick! Thanks again @June7 haha.
Here's the final sql for the append query I was working on:

INSERT INTO Table1 ( Field4 )
SELECT IIf([Field4]="100","180",IIf([Field4]="180","A1",IIf([Field4] Like "A?","A" & Mid([Field4],2)+1,IIf([Field4] Like "A1?","A" & Mid([Field4],2)+1,IIf([Field4] Like "A2?","A" & Mid([Field4],2)+2))))) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Field3)=True));